# Mutable sets in NSManagedObjects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

The standard declaration for an autogenerated `NSManagedObject` property declares to-many relationships like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *somethings;
...
@dynamic somethings;
```

Would it be safe to change that declaration to an `NSMutableSet`? Would the CoreData component still function correctly?

Judging by the `@dynamic`, it probaby doesn't care if I use an `NSSet` subclass rather than an `NSSet`, but I don't want to rewrite a lot of code only to find out it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW1), this should always be declared as a NSSet.

If you want a mutable proxy (which is basically the mutable version of the core data set and works exactly the same) then you would use the function `mutableSetValueForKey` like this:

```
// myManagedObject is the managed object that has the somethings property.
NSMutableSet *mutableSomethings = [myManagedObject mutableSetValueForKey:@"somethings"];
```

`mutableSomethings` can then be modified as a standard NSMutableSet and`somethings` will be updated and KVO methods will be appropriately called.

Note however, that many features of the mutable set (such as  `addSomethingsObject` and `removeSomethingsObject`) are already provided in the core data generated accessors so in many cases you don't need to use the proxy.

Answer (score 6):

You should keep it as an `NSSet` and do one of the following:

1. Use [key value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW1)
2. Add the core [data generated accessors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html)

For key value coding, you'll access your collection like so:

```
NSMutableSet *somethings = [object mutableSetValueForKey:@"somethings"];
[somethings addObject:newObject];
```

For core data generated accessors, you'd add the following to your header:

```
@interface MyManagedObject (CoreDataGenerated)
- (void)addSomethingsObject:(MySomething *)object;
- (void)removeSomethingsObject:(MySomething *)object;
- (void)addSomethings:(NSSet *)somethings;
- (void)removeSomethings:(NSSet *)somethings;
@end
```

You do not need to implement these methods (Core Data will take care of it for you), and you can call them easily. This is my preferred way of handling collections because you get better type checking from the compiler.

The reason you should not change it to an `NSMutableSet` is because there is a good chance that you will cause crashes and/or that your changes will not be persisted into your Core Data store.

You may also want to look into [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) to help you out with creating all of your Cocoa classes.

Comment: will it cause any problem if I add already present object to the relation

Comment: @Johnykutty sets ensure that there are no duplicates. This should have no effect.