# Insert objects into NSSet's with multiple many-to-many relationships in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, many-to-many, nsset

Let's say I have a sports app with 2 Entities. (this is purely an example)

Teams and Players.

```
class Team:NSManagedObject{
    @NSManaged var name:String
    @NSManaged var players:NSSet
}

class Player:NSManagedObject{
    @NSManaged var firstName:String
    @NSManaged var lastName:String
    @NSManaged var playsFor:NSSet
}
```

Each Team has a set of players.
Each player has a set of teams they play for.

So in essence, I have 2 many-to-many relationships. Had there only been one, I could use the inverse to insert the object into its set without any trouble.

Because of this sad dual many-to-many structure of these object, I find myself in a pickle. Now before someone says I should take an intermediate object and do a one-to-many with that object to remove the second object, I would LOVE to do that, but, in this case, I can't, so I'd like to open the topic of how to solve this particular problem.

I've tried two different attempts.

The biggest issue is that the type of players is an NSSet, I can't just do an addObject because NSSet is immutable.

My first idea was the following:

```
func addPlayer(player: Player) {
    var allPlayers = self.players.allObjects
    allPlayers.append(player)
    self.players = NSSet(array: allPlayers)
}
```

Now this is bad on multiple levels. So I'll just move on right away.

My next idea was that clearly it was bad to be taking a NSSet to an Array to a Set again just to add one item, so I changed the data model of the `Team` to be

```
@NSManagedObject var players:Set<Player>
```

Then my method was simplified to:

```
func addPlayer(player: Player) {
    self.players.addObject(player)
}
```

I really liked this, until I turned on the profiler and my execution time had actually become SIGNIFICANTLY worse.

So my next attempt was the following, clearly leaving the types of the managedobjects as NSSet gives you some significant benefits, so I didn't mess with that anymore.

```
func addPlayer(player: Players) {        
    let allPlayers = NSMutableSet(set: self.players)
    allPlayers.addObject(player)
    self.players = allPlayers
}
```

I got a small speed bump off of the last change but am still not happy with it. What other optimizations are possible? Any ideas?

In reality, I am working with an application using a VERY old database with hundreds of thousands of objects that we have no control over refactoring. I'm trying to do optimizations without completely reworking the data-model and destroying a front end. Any help advice or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `mutableSetValueForKey` against your `NSManagedObject` instance to get a mutable set that automatically updates the underlying set - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662131/mutable-sets-in-nsmanagedobjects

Comment: Fantastic! I just had found that actually on my own as well, and it did provide a speed bump, not huge but nonetheless an increase